# Is there a tool to convert SVG line paths from absolute to relative?

Tags: svg, line

Looking for a tool to convert something like

```
M10 20L0 0 5 5 10 10
```

from the absolute position to relative, something like:

```
M10 20l-10 -20 5 5 5 5
```

Notice the uppercase `L` for absolute and lowercase `l` for relative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a tool called Inkscape which allows saving to relative.

To do this:

1. New document, create a random pencil path, and save the SVG. Close inkscape.
2. Edit saved file in a text editor. Find and replace the pencil path with your path
3. Re-open the document in Inkscape. Locate and move your path. Save.
4. Edit the file again and look for the new relative path.

TADA

Comment: No longer true or reliable. Inkscape calculates which path segment will be shorter and picks absolute or relative notation based on that. You move a shape a few pixels too close to coordinate grid and you will see absolute instructions injected. see http://inkscape-forum.andreas-s.net/topic/1968810

Answer (score 17):

1. Open Inkscape and select **File**, **Inkscape Preferences** (or Shift + Ctrl + P)
2. Select **SVG output**
3. In the **path data** section untick **Allow relative coordinates** or select **always use absolute coordinates** depending on your version of Inkscape.

   This will only affect newly created paths or existing objects for which a rewrite of the path data is triggered. For existing paths:
4. Select **Edit**, then **Select All in All Layers**.
5. Use the **arrow key** to nudge the selection (e.g. one step up and one back down again). This will trigger a rewrite of the path data in `d` which will follow the changed preferences for absolute path values.

This works for Inkscape 0.48

Comment: Thanks for saving my day! I was going nuts after setting the preferences and yet seeing no change in the result. The extre nudge step was exactly what I needed :D

Comment: Note: **the layers must be visible** for the selection to work.

Comment: This preference appears to have moved as of Inkscape 1.0.x. It is now located at Edit > Preferences > Input/Output > SVG Output.  For the Path data "Path string format", select "Relative".

Answer (score 5):

For who's still searching for this tool. There is one made by Lea Verou on codepen that convert paths to relative or absolute.

Example convert this:

```
M233.51,56.8c-0.57,0.24-1.33,0.52-2.28,0.86c-0.95,0.33-1.93,0.5-2.92,0.5s-1.84-0.27-2.53-0.82
c-0.69-0.55-1.03-1.49-1.03-2.82V36.25h7.85V28.9h-7.85V16.77h-9.56V28.9h-17.84V16.77h-9.56V28.9h-4.92v7.35h4.92v21.48
c0,1.67,0.26,3.08,0.79,4.25c0.52,1.17,1.22,2.12,2.1,2.85c0.88,0.74,1.9,1.27,3.07,1.61c1.16,0.33,2.41,0.5,3.75,0.5
c2.05,0,4-0.28,5.85-0.86c1.86-0.57,3.42-1.14,4.71-1.71l-1.93-7.56c-0.57,0.24-1.33,0.52-2.28,0.86c-0.95,0.33-1.93,0.5-2.92,0.5
c-1,0-1.84-0.27-2.53-0.82c-0.69-0.55-1.03-1.49-1.03-2.82V36.25h17.84v21.48c0,1.67,0.26,3.08,0.79,4.25
c0.52,1.17,1.22,2.12,2.1,2.85c0.88,0.74,1.9,1.27,3.07,1.61c1.16,0.33,2.41,0.5,3.75,0.5c2.05,0,4-0.28,5.85-0.86
c1.86-0.57,3.42-1.14,4.71-1.71L233.51,56.
```

Into this:

```
M233.51,56.8c-0.57,0.24,-1.33,0.52,-2.28,0.86c-0.95,0.33,-1.93,0.5,-2.92,0.5s-1.84,-0.27,-2.53,-0.82c-0.69,-0.55,-1.03,-1.49,-1.03,-2.82v-18.27h7.85v-7.35h-7.85v-12.13h-9.56v12.13h-17.84v-12.13h-9.56v12.13h-4.92v7.35h4.92v21.48c0,1.67,0.26,3.08,0.79,4.25c0.52,1.17,1.22,2.12,2.1,2.85c0.88,0.74,1.9,1.27,3.07,1.61c1.16,0.33,2.41,0.5,3.75,0.5c2.05,0,4,-0.28,5.85,-0.86c1.86,-0.57,3.42,-1.14,4.71,-1.71l-1.93,-7.56c-0.57,0.24,-1.33,0.52,-2.28,0.86c-0.95,0.33,-1.93,0.5,-2.92,0.5c-1,0,-1.84,-0.27,-2.53,-0.82c-0.69,-0.55,-1.03,-1.49,-1.03,-2.82v-18.28h17.84v21.48c0,1.67,0.26,3.08,0.79,4.25c0.52,1.17,1.22,2.12,2.1,2.85c0.88,0.74,1.9,1.27,3.07,1.61c1.16,0.33,2.41,0.5,3.75,0.5c2.05,0,4,-0.28,5.85,-0.86c1.86,-0.57,3.42,-1.14,4.71,-1.71l-1.97,-7.57z
```

https://codepen.io/leaverou/pen/RmwzKv

Answer (score 2):

In settings, under **"SVG Output", set "Path string format"** to **"Absolute"** and save as plain SVG. You may have to nudge the object so Inkskape will reset the 'd' attribute for the path.