# Converting an SVG to absolute command in Ruby

Tags: ruby, svg

I see that converting SVGs to absolute commands is a common ask:

- [Is there a tool to convert SVG line paths from absolute to relative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890685/is-there-a-tool-to-convert-svg-line-paths-from-absolute-to-relative)
- [Convert SVG Path to Absolute Commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9677885/convert-svg-path-to-absolute-commands)

However, it looks like most solutions are in JavaScript:

- [Utility: Convert SVG path to all-relative or all-absolute commands](https://lea.verou.me/2019/05/utility-convert-svg-path-to-all-relative-or-all-absolute-commands/)
- [fontello/svgpath](https://github.com/fontello/svgpath)

Was wondering if anyone knew of a working solution in Ruby? Or a related tool that might make creating a solution easier? I believe it'd have to "[work out what that last coordinate is in absolute terms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41609438/how-to-split-one-path-into-two-paths-in-svg)"

I've found some Ruby projects related to SVGs but they don't seem like they'd be helpful in creating a solution:

- [DannyBen/victor](https://github.com/DannyBen/victor)
- [awebneck/savage](https://github.com/awebneck/savage)
- [aseldawy/rasem](https://github.com/aseldawy/rasem)

Hoping this already exists somewhere. I guess an alternative to creating it in Ruby is to figure out a way to execute JavaScript code in my project (API running Sinatra). I'd need to output the SVG as a string to Ruby though. I'm not sure about how to go about that or if it's feasible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, you need to work it out by yourself. Notice that an SVG file is *not* an SVG path, the former is a full-fledged XML document, while the latter is a specific attribute of some of the elements of a SVG.

So you get your path (say `M 10,10 L 20,10 40,15`), tokenize it using a finite state machine, and push fully formed tokens (adding the implicit letter repetitions) down an enumerable stream, obtaining

```rb
["M", 10, 10]
["L", 20, 10]
["L", 40, 15]
```

Then you can pass this stream to something like `each_with_object` so the object keeps track of the current position:

```rb
tokens.each_with_object([0, 0]).map do |command, current|
  case command
  in ["M", new_x, new_y]
    # compute new command with relative syntax
    modified = ["m", new_x - current.first, new_y - current.last]

    # update current position
    current.first = new_x
    current.last = new_y

    # yield the modified command
    modified
  in ["m", new_x, new_y]
    # update current position
    current.first += new_x
    current.last += new_y

    # yield the original command
    ["m", new_x, new_y]
  end
end
```

You have to add all of the SVG path commands (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d), and change the corresponding absolute ones into relative. It will take 10' maximum to complete and you'll have a working SVG tool.